# android usage of "controller.query(activity);" in scoreloop

Tags: android, controller, scoreloop

i am attempting to implement a built in controller that is part of the scoreloop library.  the documentation states:

**Basic Usage:**

To invoke the TOS dialog if it was not accepted previously, the following code may be used:

```
 final TermsOfServiceController controller = new TermsOfServiceController(new TermsOfServiceControllerObserver() {
 @Override
 public void termsOfServiceControllerDidFinish(final TermsOfServiceController controller, final Boolean accepted) {
    if(accepted != null) {
        // we have conclusive result.
        if(accepted) {
            // user did accept
        }
        else {
            // user did reject
        }
    }
 }
 });
 controller.query(activity);
```

but when i paste this into my code i get the following syntax errors:

[image: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)]
[image: Syntax error on token "activity", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token]

am i using this incorrectly?  how and where would this be used any ideas?

EDIT: after moving the statement to the method where i want to show the dialog i now get the following error:

[image: new error]

Comment: What value of activity you are putting there?? i.e. value of activity variable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling `controller.query(activity)` in a class body where a declaration is expected. Move the statement `controller.query(activity)` to a method where you would like to show the dialog.

Comment: yes this makes a lot more sense.  however i still have no idea what i should be passing to "activity" what type of object should it even be?  i now get the following error:  ![activity cannot be resolved to a variable.][1]
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CfZhL.jpg

Comment: If the type of your class is some type of `Activity`, pass `this` in the `query` method. Sorry, I am not familiar with scoreloop.

Comment: This may make your code compile, but most probably, you won't be able to run it. You have to find the reference to the `Activity` instance and pass it.

Comment: no it did what i needed to, basically it invoked the TOS dialog if it was not accepted previously.